# laravel + character missing while $request->get()

Tags: php, laravel, request

I need a bit of help here.

When I print `$request` and `$request->fullUrl()`,  it prints as follows

```
POST /web/abcd/example?id=1&email=++a@a.com HTTP/1.1
Accept:           application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
.
.
.
```

and

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/web/abcd/example?email=%20%20a%40a.com&id=2
```

But when I try to read query parameter by `$request->get('email')` it returns   `a@a.com` instead of `++a@a.com`. How can I get the correct email? Help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must encode the + character before putting it query parameter.

%2B is url encoded form of + character. Try putting %2B instead of +.

You may read it in for more details. [PHP: url encode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)